# Spaces in Image Names

Tags: assets

Since updating to Assets 2.2.2, any images that were uploaded with spaces in the file name are now completely absent from the front end. Is there a quick fix for this or do I need to go into Assets and rename all of the images?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that; but it's generally not a good practice to allow spaces in file, directory, or image names. You may want to initiate that standard for all future images.